# why should i use _underscore methods why not jquery methods in backbone.js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

can I use $.each() method instead of _each() in backbone implementation code .
is there any performance improvements for the same code by using underscore methods?

Comment: beside of the rude nature of this comment, it's also not very constructive

Answer (score 1):

underscore.js is part of backbone, so it's already included ;)

If youre interested in performance, have a look at this

http://jsperf.com/test-jquery-each-vs-each

underscore is a bit faster

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Either or will do, according to http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-underscore-each-vs-for-loops/4, just using plain for loops is faster, but the underscore method preformed better. I suggest you try your own tests as well, because this is only a single tests cas eon a single platform, you may find different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in Backbone without any issues. Backbone itself has chosen to use Underscore, because it is a more lightweight solution, and Backbone aims to be minimal library. (In this case, by lightweight, I mean that the minified Underscore library is about 5kB, the latest jQuery is nearly 100kB in size.)

You are not forced to use Underscore yourself, if you need jQuery for some reason, then by all means, use it. As for performance: you can't really say anything in general, you have to make measurements if you want meaningful results.